# ORA-907: missing right parenthesis and am I doing this right?

Tags: sql

I'm kind of new to SQL.

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, MAX(count(CONTRACT_CLIENT)

FROM CONTRACT JOIN EMPLOYER ON (CONTRACT_ID = EMP_ID)

WHERE EMP_ID = CONTRACT_ID;
```

it comes up with missing right parenthesis. Feel completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to find the employee with the maximum contract count.  Here is one approach:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, CC_CNT
FROM
(
    SELECT EMP_NAME, COUNT(CONTRACT_CLIENT) AS CC_CNT
    FROM CONTRACT
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYER ON CONTRACT_ID = EMP_ID
    GROUP BY EMP_NAME
    ORDER BY COUNT(CONTRACT_CLIENT) DESC
) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

The key steps you were missing include aggregating by employee using `GROUP BY`. And also, you can't nest a call to `COUNT` inside `MAX`.  Instead, use a `rownum` trick to find the employee with the highest count.

Comment: emp refers to employer which is the client, consultant is the employee. I'm looking for which employer has the most contracts with us

Comment: Oops...then I guess `EMP_NAME` must mean "Employer Name."  No matter, I still think the logic I have given you above is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your SQL query will return the correct output but I am fixing the parenthesis issue for you.

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, MAX(COUNT(CONTRACT_CLIENT))
FROM CONTRACT 
JOIN EMPLOYER ON (CONTRACT_ID = EMP_ID)
WHERE EMP_ID = CONTRACT_ID;
```

Comment: If you are only fixing a typo, then please don't answer, instead vote to close as a typo question (but there are many other problems beyond this).